# writing output of xbacklight -get to a variable in a bash script

Tags: shell-script, zenity

I have a little script that lets me set the display brightness

```
#!/bin/sh

VALUE=$(zenity --scale --text="Select Display brightness" --value=50 --title "Helligkeit anpassen");
xbacklight -set $VALUE;
```

Now I want the default value not to be 50, but the current brightness.

So I altered the script and did:

```
#!/bin/sh
var=$(xbacklight -get);

VALUE=$(zenity --scale --text="Select Display brightness" --value=$var --title "Helligkeit anpassen");
xbacklight -set $VALUE;
```

But  apparently, the line:

```
var=$(xbacklight -get);
```

Does not work, if I open up a terminal `xbacklight -get` runs just fine and returns a number.

I also tried the [other variants described here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-appleosx-bash-assign-variable-command-output/) or to directly do `--value='xbacklight -get'`. But all did not work.

I'm really confused.

Comment: Did you try running zenity outside of the command substitution and checking for error messages? On my system, it looks like `xbacklight --get` returns a decimal value, whereas `zenity --value=` only accepts integers. If that's what's breaking it here, you could simply trim the decimal component e.g.  `--value="${var%.*}"`

Comment: What error remains, exactly? what is the output of `echo $var` in that case?

Comment: That was exactly the problem. I failed to comprehend the error message. @steeldriver Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

as @steeldriver correctly pointed out, one needs to make sure an integer is used as input for the `--value` option.

This script runs just fine

```
#!/bin/sh
# set display brightness with a zenity gui
var=$(xbacklight -get);

VALUE=$(zenity --scale --text="select display brightness" --value="${var%.*}" --title "adjust brightness");
xbacklight -set $VALUE;
```